# Create Folder on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I created a new project on Visual Studio Team Services (formerly VSO) but I can't create a folder under the project -- online or through Visual Studio. Online, I just don't even see an option. Under Visual Studio, the New Folder is grayed out -- see below:
[image]
[image]

How do I create folder under this new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map that server path to local (click Not mapped link), otherwise it doesn’t know where to create folder, after that check in changes to server. (You can't create the folder in server directly)

[image]

Comment: One follow up question, if I may. I haven't mapped it yet because I already have a project locally. Basically I was getting ready to check it into a new repo on VSTS. Just want to make sure that mapping it first won't screw things up. I'm always very nervous with this. Here's what I was trying to do: Create a folder, then convert it to a branch named "Dev". After that I was going to map and check my code in so that the code goes into the Dev branch. Is my sequence wrong?